# Is there a shell command to open Ethernet settings?

Tags: networking, shell

To open the Wi-Fi settings, one can use the following command:

```
 # am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$AdvancedWifiSettingsActivity
```

Is there a similar command to open the Ethernet settings as following?
[image]

Comment: @AaronGillion  I added a screenshot per your request.

Comment: Woah, that's awesome. What device is this??

Comment: @AaronGillion It is just a generic tablet.  At least many tablets support Ethernet. One could plug in a USB-to-Ethernet adapter to enable Ethernet.

Comment: @Hong Since you're asking, I assume that `am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$EthernetSettingsActivity` does not work, correct?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I thought I tried it, or something similar, and it did not work. I tried it again a moment ago, and it worked.   Could you turn your comment as the answer, so I can accept it.  I was looking at this page:https://github.com/Mirkoddd/Settings.apk/tree/master/smali/com/android/settings, but could not find anything related to Ethernet.  Where can I find all the possible settings activities?

Comment: @Hong I included the method I used in the answer below. Since its output is far from being refined, you may wish to perform further research and improve my answer with your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to launch the **Ethernet Activity** of the Settings, is to issue:

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$EthernetSettingsActivity
```

in a terminal.

By the way, the method to obtain an unrefined list of all the activities in an app, is to extract such data directly from the **AndroidManifest.xml**. Luckily, we can accomplish this with the following terminal commands:

```
path=$(pm path com.android.settings)
path=${path#p*:}
aapt d xmltree $path AndroidManifest.xml | grep Settings\$. > /sdcard/SettingsActivities.txt
```

Now, the first line assigns to the variable `path` the path where to find the **Settings** apk. This is useful if you need to include this snippet in a script, and you want to make it portable for various Android flavors.

Line 2 sanitizes the path variable, by removing the **"package:"** prefix set by `pm path`, thus making it usable for the third line.

Line 3 does the real job: it dumps the **AndroidManifest.xml** of the app indicated in the `path` variable. It also filters the output, in order to consider only the lines which contain **"Settings$"**, and then outputs the result, saving it to a file with an arbitrary name (here **SettingsActivities.txt**), for further examination.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extraordinary elucidation!  I tried those commands, but got /system/bin/sh: aapt: not found.

Comment: Yeah, your device may be one of those that doesn't ship `aapt` by default. You'll be able to address this issue by downloading the first aapt from http://www.izzysoft.de/ftp/local/android/ , unpack it, and install it on the System partition by following the info provided in the **readme.md** file (by the way, that site belongs to Izzy, famed Android SE moderator).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I am all set.  Since I may do this for different devices, I pulled settings.apk to my computer and used Android SDK's aapt to extract the information based on your tip.

Comment: [*"There is no such activity in **standard Android"***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15866306/9165920)